# Propositional formulas 3

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What are the difference between:

$A \implies (B \implies C)$, $\ (A \implies B) \implies C$, $\ A\land B \implies C$, $\ A \implies B \land C$, $\ (A \implies B)\land (B \implies C)$?

Why we can not write $A \implies B \implies C$?

And the same questions about:

$A \iff(B \iff C)$, $\ (A \iff B) \iff C$, $\ A\land B \iff C$, $\ A \iff B \land C$, $\ (A  \iff B)\land(B \iff C)$?

Why we can not write $A \iff B \iff C$?

Can someone explain me this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can work out the differences with truth tables, or you can note that $p\to q$ is equivalent to $q\hbox{ OR NOT }p,$ and for the second case, that $p\leftrightarrow q$ is equivalent to $(p\hbox{ AND }q)\hbox{ OR }(\hbox{ NOT }p\hbox{ AND NOT }q$).

Then, once you have established that brackets can change the meaning of an expression, writing something like $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ becomes ambiguous.

For $$A\leftrightarrow B\leftrightarrow C$$ the story is slightly different. There we have that the truth value is independent of the order of evaluation, but both are distinct from the usual interpretation as "$A\leftrightarrow B$ AND $B \leftrightarrow C$".

Comment: what about why we can to write  A → B → C ?

Comment: If you apply two operations to three operands then you need some convention about the order of operations. You can always write $A\to B\to C$ (you and I just did it) but what do you *mean* by it? If it has any meaning different from $(A\to B)\to C$ then you should clarify that (nonstandard) meaning.

Comment: i understand.Only one question is it the same when we say A ↔ B ↔ C ?

Comment: Exactly. Once you have established that $(A\leftrightarrow B)\leftrightarrow C$ is different from $A\leftrightarrow (B\leftrightarrow C)$ an expression such as $A\leftrightarrow B\leftrightarrow C$ becomes ambiguous.

Comment: A↔B↔C makes for a relatively poor example, since ↔ associates.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood agreed that there may be ambiguity in the example, thanks. BTW I do not think that $\leftrightarrow$ associates.

Comment: It does associate in the sense that for whatever truth value ((A↔B)↔C) has, (A↔(B↔C)) has the same truth value also.

Comment: Correct, I got confused for a moment.

Answer (score -1):

The relation A -> (B -> C) says that C will come from B if A is present.  This makes no relation between A and B, it can be written as A=Policemen B=naughty boys C=good boys.  The policemen makes naughty boys become good boys.

(A->B) -> C would equate to Policemen make naughty boys, which give good boys as a result.